# Can't install packages on Raspberry Pi with apt-get

Tags: update, raspbian-buster

I originally had a problem installing packages on a Raspberry Pi 2 Model A with an older version of Raspbian.  So downloaded the July 2019 of Raspbian Buster Lite, and it installed ok.  But it has the same problem with installs:

```
sudo apt update
Get:1 http://raspbian.raspberrypi.org/raspbian buster InRelease
Get:2 http://archive.raspberrypi.org/debian buster InRelease
Err:1 http://raspbian.raspberrypi.org/raspbian buster InRelease
  Undetermined Error [IP: 192.168.1.254 80]
Err:2 http://archive.raspberrypi.org/debian buster InRelease
  Undetermined Error [IP: 192.168.1.254 80]
```

and it when I try to install packages it cannot find them.  For example

```
sudo apt install python-pip
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree       
Reading state information... Done
E: Unable to locate package python-pip
```

It's on Wifi and it can fetch webpages with wget.  I have tried

```
sudo apt update --allow-releaseinfo-change
```

but it doesn't help.

Comment: Whatever your problem actually is, it is obvious that your network is incorrectly setup because it is looking on your local network. Forget update - get the internet working first.

Comment: "It's on Wifi and it can fetch webpages with wget" - are you behind an HTTP proxy?

Comment: Thanks Both.  No HTTP proxy AFAIK. Traceroute gives: traceroute to ox.ac.uk (129.67.242.155), 30 hops max, 60 byte packets
 1  dsldevice.lan (192.168.1.254)  8.881 ms  8.367 ms  12.129 ms
 2  * * *
etc.

Comment: Traceroute to `ox.ac.uk` isn't important. Try traceroute to `raspbian.raspberrypi.org`.

Comment: @Ingo traceroute to raspbian.raspberrypi.org (93.93.128.193), 30 hops max, 60 byte packets
 1  dsldevice.lan (192.168.1.254)  14.627 ms  14.072 ms  13.582 ms,2 * * *, 3 * * * etc.  But not sure why the Pi's IP address 192.168.1.77 does not show in this route.

Comment: @Phileas Does the route finish before 30 hops?

Comment: @Ingo.  No.  Here we are: cat index.html
<!-- Page(9146)=[ Internet access blocked by BT Access Control].  I wonder if this is an incorrectly configured firewall.  But I'm with Plusnet, not BT, and I can't see anything wrong with the setup, which worked for other Pis on the network.

Comment: Like this poster, https://community.plus.net/t5/My-Router/PlusNet-Hub-One-quot-Access-Blocked-quot-BY-Smart-Hub-Manager/td-p/1506370 I assumed that the Plusnet firmware had not been rebranded.  Some weirdness going on here.